# Google Container Registry and private docker registry

Tags: google-container-registry

As described on Google Container Registry.the GCR can work as a cached images store to public images on docker hub.
What if my images on docker hub is private?

Answer (score 0):

There is a restriction on Docker hub to mirror private registry, it is not restricted in GCR. You can find this [document](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/) where it is stated that, “It’s currently not possible to mirror another private registry. Only the central Hub can be mirrored.”

Comment: Okay.Is there another way to mirror private registry?Because I want to images built auto refer to Dockerfiles.

Comment: No from Docker Hub. You can use continuous delivery tool integrations[0], Google has Cloud Build[1] to create the image [2] and push to Container Registry [3]. You can build and push images to private registry when you commit code to Cloud Source Repositories, GitHub [4], or Bitbucket[5].

Comment: [0] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/continuous-delivery
[1] https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/integrating-with-cloud-build#using_a_dockerfile
[2] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts
[3] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/
[4] https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository
[5] https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository